# windows r inside rcpp eclipse

Tags: eclipse, r, rcpp, rinside

I'm trying to use Rinside in an IDE, Eclipse. Follow step by step manual

http://blog.fellstat.com/?p=170

However, when you Build All I mark the following errors

```
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:55:17: error: 'internal' does not name a type
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:68:21: error: expected ')' before 'charsxp'
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:73:23: error: 'StringProxy' does not name a type
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:73:36: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'proxy' with no type [-fpermissive]
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:92:23: error: expected ')' before 'x'
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:97:35: error: declaration of 'operator=' as non-function
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:97:32: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:97:41: error: expected ')' before 'x'
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:100:35: error: declaration of 'operator=' as non-function
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:100:32: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:100:40: error: expected ')' before 'x'
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:103:41: error: 'StringProxy' does not name a type
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:103:54: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'proxy' with no type [-fpermissive]
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:125:42: error: 'StringProxy' does not name a type
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:125:55: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'proxy' with no type [-fpermissive]
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:133:36: error: declaration of 'operator+=' as non-function
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:133:32: error: expected ';' at end of member declaration
C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp/string.h:133:41: error: expected ')' before 'x'
In file included from c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/cwchar:46:0,
                 from c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/bits/postypes.h:42,
                 from c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iosfwd:42,
                 from c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/ios:39,
                 from c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/ostream:40,
                     from c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-    mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../include/c++/4.6.3/iterator:64,
             from C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:57,
             from C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
             from ../src/main.cpp:12:
    c:\r\rtools\gcc-4.6.3\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.6.3/../../../../i686-w64-    mingw32/include/wchar.h:12:32: error: expected '}' before end of line
In file included from C:/R/R-2.15.2/include/R_ext/RS.h:26:0,
             from C:/R/R-2.15.2/include/R.h:44,
             from C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/RcppCommon.h:32,
             from C:/R/R-2.15.2/library/Rcpp/include/Rcpp.h:27,
             from ../src/main.cpp:12:
```

And the error list continues

Somebody help me, really I did everything and nothing helps.

thanks

Comment: I guess the error is not Eclipse specific.  Maybe try to get a working system first, and then try to get it working from Eclipse?

Comment: I answered this question in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15489065/rcppeclipse-on-mac-os-x/17054405